# Determine time of impact of two spheres

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am creating a 3D gravity simulation in Unity. I have everything working correctly except the collision response. I want to make collision resolve calculations from the exact point of impact rather than the time of the current timestep. I have looked around, and I think I have found the correct equation to determine the exact time of collision. However, whenever I try to execute the code, I am getting a NaN error as a result. I have tried everything I can think of to fix the issue, but nothing seems to remedy the error. Can someone take a look at my code and see if you can identify any obvious errors I may have missed?

The method I am having trouble with was designed to determine the exact time of impact between two spheres which I know have collide within the last timestep. If each timestep is 1, the method is meant to return a number between 0(the current timestep) and 1(the previous timestep) that the collision occurred.

[This is the formula I am using](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36186/what-is-the-general-approach-to-calculating-time-of-impact-in-3d)

```
Vector3 velocity2MinusVelocity1 = particle2.GetComponent<Particle>().Velocity - particle1.GetComponent<Particle>().Velocity;
        Vector3 separationVector = particle1.transform.position - particle2.transform.position;

        return ((-(Vector3.Dot(separationVector, velocity2MinusVelocity1)
                / (Mathf.Pow(Vector3.Magnitude(velocity2MinusVelocity1), 2))))
                -
                (Mathf.Sqrt(
                    Mathf.Pow(
                        Vector3.Dot(separationVector, velocity2MinusVelocity1) 
                        / Mathf.Pow(Vector3.Magnitude(velocity2MinusVelocity1), 2)
                        , 2)
                    - 
                        Mathf.Pow(Vector3.Magnitude(separationVector), 2) 
                            - Mathf.Pow(particle1.GetComponent<Particle>().Radius 
                                + particle2.GetComponent<Particle>().Radius
                            ,2)
                        / Mathf.Pow(Vector3.Magnitude(velocity2MinusVelocity1), 2)
                )));
```

I apologize if the structure is a little hard to follow. I tried to make it as easily readable as possible

Comment: Mathematical code (the area in which I specialise) should always be documented. In short, momentum is conserved in every dimension and don't forget to add the radius of the balls. Spin makes things difficult; you need to conserve angular momentum too. Looks like you're ignoring that (no sin in doing that) as I can't see the moment of inertia of a sphere anywhere in your code.

Comment: This method wasn't designed to resolve the collision (ie. make changes to any elements of the position, velocity, etc.): it's purpose is merely to find the exact time of impact (so as to be more precise than using the measurements at the current time step.) Sorry if I wasn't clear on that earlier.

Comment: Your code is unreadable, it's not surprising you can't find the problem. One thing mentioned in the equation you're copying that I don't see handled is "Duration τc is required to be "real", therefore the term under the square root must not be negative." If you're computing the square root of a negative number I'd guess that's where the NaN is coming from.

Comment: Similar question on GameDev.SE: [What is a good algorithm to detect collision between moving spheres?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-is-a-good-algorithm-to-detect-collision-between-moving-spheres)